# Intellij Idea 12 community edition svn

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I was wondering is it only me or the intellij community 12 has problems connecting to SVN (version 1.6). Every time i enter the url to checkout the project it just hangs out and after a long time it returns with a message that the server refused the connection. With the version 11 it is working correctly.

thanks

Comment: Does it happen with [IDEA 12.0.2 release](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) and [12.0.3 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP)? What SVN protocol is used to access the server? Anything related in idea.log (`Help` | `Reveal Log in ...`)?

Comment: Here too, the problem started from version 12.04. It still exists in 12.1. I'm Working with SVN 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is an Intellij bug.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-100494